# Cassandra Nodetool status is not showing correct used space

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

I am facing one issue with our Cassandra cluster.

**Details**: Cassandra 3.0.14, 12 nodes, 7.4TB(JBOD) disk size in each node, ~3.5TB used physical data in each node, ~42TB whole cluster and default compaction setup. This size maintain the same because after the retention period some tables are dropped.

**Issue**: Nodetool status is not showing the correct used size in the output. It keeps increasing the used size without limit until automatically node shutdown or until our sequential scheduled restart(workaround 3 times week). After the restart, nodetool shows the correct used space but for few days.
Did anybody have similar problem? Is it a bug?

Comment: That was a bug in Cassandra - but I can't find the issue ID...

Comment: possibly this? https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/207852056-Nodetool-status-showing-incorrect-data-load-values-after-incremental-repair

Comment: It is not related to CASSANDRA-10430, because we don't run the repair and we guarantee the consistency by RF=3 and CL=QUORUM. It is heavy load environment, few ready access.